# javascript reports that "$" and "alert" are undefined

Tags: javascript, jquery, eslint

Just embarking in learning yet another language (JavaScript) and following instructions from a tutorial. I have node and Brackets (the editor) installed. The tutorial was requesting the following to be put in a file named 
"app.js":

```
$('form').on('submit',function () {
    var text = $('#message').val();
    alert(text);
    return false;
});
```

The problem I have is that the system immediately complains that `"$"` (two places) and `"alert"` are **undefined**.

The `index.html` file was originally requested to specify:

```
   <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.1.js"></script>
   <script src="app.js"></script>
```

at the bottom (which caused the system to complain with an earlier simplified version about 'alert') but I replaced it with the following after visiting the `code.jquery.com` site:

```
   <script
     src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.js"
     integrity="sha256-2Kok7MbOyxpgUVvAk/HJ2jigOSYS2auK4Pfzbm7uH60="
     crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
   <script src="app.js"></script>
```

This solved the alert issue when the .js file was nothing more than a 'hello world', but now I have a "problem++" with the next version of the `.js` file shown above.

I suppose it could be something about the installation and/or paths; but I am at a loss figuring where that could be and how to fix it. Can any expert suggest something?

For the record: I am on a Windows 7 machine, using Chrome to display the html file.

Many thanks

Edit:
additional complete text of 'index.html' file:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
<main>
  <ol id="history">
<li>commander says: no offence, but you are a robot, aren't you?</li>   
<li>roobie says: that is correct, sir</li>
<li>cookie says: hey doc, is that a male or a female? </li>   
<li>robbie says: this information is meaningless</li>
  </ol>
  <form>
    <input id="initials">
    <input id="message">
    <button>Send</button>
  </form>
</main>
<script
  src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.js"
  integrity="sha256-2Kok7MbOyxpgUVvAk/HJ2jigOSYS2auK4Pfzbm7uH60="
  crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="app.js"></script>
```

Comment: I don't think we have enough information. Can you please post the entirety of your `index.html` and `app.js` files?

Comment: The app.js file in its entirety is at the beginning of the question. I have added the complete 'index.html'

Comment: Can you post the exact error? Including where in the code that the console is complaining about. I suspect it's Line 1 of app.js. But just double checking...

Comment: The following 3 errors were listed in "eslint" section:
ERROR: '$' is not defined [no undef]   $('form').on('submit',function () {
ERROR: '$' is not defined [no undef]     var text = $('#message').val();
ERROR: 'alert'  is not defined [no undef]   alert(text);

So it is complaining about line 1, 2 and 3

Comment: How does node.js relate to this? HTML is loaded on the client, node.js runs on the server.

Comment: Honestly, I do not know. I assume that 'node' is the JavaScript engine being called, isn't it? The tutorial was calling for the installation of Node.js, Brackets and Chrome; but did not provide any specifics about configuration hence my uncertainty regarding the suitability of the default installation parameters. I already had Chrome, and installed the other two.
With this tutorial, we are supposed to run both the client and the server sides.

Comment: The way the thing (does not) work, when trying the next step of the tutorial -- adding statements in a "server.js" file -- is that Brackets complains about other advanced features. It reports not finding 'require' and not finding 'console', which I would venture means it fails to bind something. That seems like  a path or configuration issue more than anything I can think of, but what is the solution?

Comment: eslint errors? *Try actually running the code*. It's likely eslint just doesn't know what jquery adds. In the browser, you can see errors in the dev tools (F12) What ide are you using?

Comment: I cannot run the code if the ide (Brackets, I think that was clear) complains about the compilation.

Answer (score -1):

did you add the jquery link twice?
Please remove all jquery links and do the following:

1. remove all previous jquery links.
2. Add this code snippet between your head tags.

   ```
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
   ```

Comment: No, there is only one jquery reference; the one originally listed at the beginning of the question was replaced by the block listed after. Replacing code reference source from code.jquery.com to the suggested 'ajax' source returns the same error messages concerning a non definition of "$" and "alert".
I am open to the possibility of a complete re-install of the various tools if they happen to be at the wrong place to see each other, if there is a suggested path location for each component, but that installation proceeded without offering a placement selection, making this perhaps dubious.